# Html5 form validation dont display error with data slide

Tags: css, html, forms, validation

I have a form validation using the html5, but when the form is inside a certain div, the validation doesnt work.

The div:

```
div class="slide story" id="slide-6" data-slide="6">
...
</div>
```

If the form is out of this div it works fine! But when this div surround the form the validation doens't work.
The Css:

```
#slide-6 {
background-color: #00387F;
color: #e4e6e5;
padding-bottom: 350px;
padding-top: 90px;
}

.contact-info .contact-content{
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-info p{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-info p i{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.contact-form{}

.contact-form input[type="text"],
.contact-form input[type="email"]{
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-form textarea{
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
#slide-6 {
    background-image: none;
}
}

#slide-6 .line-row .hr {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#slide-6 a {
    color: inherit;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.with-hover-text{
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
}

#contact-row-4 {
    padding-top: 125px;
}

#contact-row-4 .col-12 {
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    transition: all ease-in .5s;
}

#contact-row-4 img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#contact-row-4 .col-12:hover {
    height: 175px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

#contact-row-4 .col-12 .hover-text {
    display: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

The form:

```
<div class="slide story" id="slide-6" data-slide="6">
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
                <form action="php/send-contact.php" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Name*">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email*">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <textarea name="message" required="required" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-send">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you paste more HTML example of your form?

Comment: sorry, I edit the question

Comment: Its working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/1/

Comment: for me is not working, lol, anyway, thanks for trying